# TFS Build missing Castle Windsor

Tags: tfs, nuget, castle-windsor

I used NuGet to add CastleWindsor to a project. Eveything works ok.

When I check it into tfs, I get the following message.

> Unable to find version '3.3.3' of package 'Castle.Core'.

Any idea how I can get the build server to get the new version of Castle.Core?

Comment: I'm guessing you build doesn't perform a package restore?

Comment: How can I do this with the xml version of a build definition?

Comment: What's your TFS version? And which build system are you using? vNext or XAML?

Comment: TFS 2012 and XAML

Answer (score 2):

First just as Dave commented, please check if you have add the [nuget install task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-installer) in your build definition and before your build task.

Also make sure you are using the right version of Nuget. For example, if you already use V3.0 and the config file are still point to V2.0. You will get this error.

[image]

Moreover, double check if the packages can be restored successfully on you dev PC and build agent manually, you can also compare the nuget.config file on your TFS server and dev PCs to see if there is any difference between them. The nuget.config file locates at `"%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config"`.

Answer (score 0):

TFS2012 does not restore the nuget packages automatically, you need to add a build step to call the nuget command to restore the nuget packages. Refer to this link for details: [Package Restore with Team Foundation Build](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore#package-restore-with-team-foundation-build).

> With TFS 2013 and later, packages are automatically restored by
>   default during build, provided that you're using a Team Build Template
>   for Team Foundation Server 2013 or later.
>
> If you're using a previous version of build templates (such as in a
>   project that's been migrated from earlier versions of TFS), you'll
>   need to also migrate those build templates to TFS 2013. This
>   essentially means recreating the custom parts of the Build Templates
>   using the appropriate template for your source control (TFVC or Git).
>
> **For earlier version of TFS, you can simply include a build step to
>   invoke command-line restore as described earlier.**